# Unable to start the daemon process.. i tried a lot of answers on that but nothing work for me...so i decide to ask it with full deails

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I tried a lot of solutions, like invalidating the caches and restarted many times, and started with admin permission, and updated android studio, deleted gradle folder from user/user.

gradle..of 1.5 gb. install the files again...

[image: enter image description]

[image: enter image description]

```
My OS windows 8.1
Android studio 3.1.3
jvm:opem jdk 64 bit server
build versions are shown in screen shot
```

The following is the log file ..idea file it is very big in length apprx 40k characters so I copy pasted some part of that which can be help full to understand the issue.

> 2018-07-14 11:28:47,043 [ thread 25]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3s 531ms) 
>   2018-07-14 11:28:47,075 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
>   2018-07-14 11:28:47,075 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'F:\Last Smester\DriveEscueV2.2' DriveEscueV2.2 
>   2018-07-14 11:28:47,340 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-14 11:28:47,340 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
>   2018-07-14 11:28:47,372 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang -
>
> 2018-07-15 20:49:29,301 [d thread 9]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> 2018-07-15 20:49:29,301 [d thread 9]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3s 406ms) 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,301 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,301 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'F:\Last Smester\DriveEscueV2.2' DriveEscueV2.2 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
>   2018-07-15 20:49:29,442 [ thread 11]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:51:10,763 [ thread 12]   WARN - dea.sdk.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80' 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:41,907 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'DriveEscueV2.2'. 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:41,912 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:41,912 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project 'F:\Last Smester\DriveEscueV2.2' DriveEscueV2.2 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:41,938 [ thread 11]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:41,947 [ thread 11]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:42,008 [ thread 11]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.1 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.1.3.0 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script C:\Users\husnainbutt\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle --offline 
>   2018-07-15 20:53:47,848 [ thread 11]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
>   org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip'.
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:283)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       ... 1 more
>
> 2018-07-15 20:54:42,698 [ thread 20]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> 2018-07-15 20:54:42,698 [ thread 20]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3s 318ms) 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,714 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,714 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'F:\Last Smester\DriveEscueV2.2' DriveEscueV2.2 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,761 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,761 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:42,792 [ thread 17]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2018-07-15 20:54:51,009 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
>   Exit code 1

Comment: Help me Obi wan Kenobi you're my only hope!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Do you have any proxy or any VPN that blocks the URL : 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip' try running this url on any browser and see if it start downloading..

Comment: I have no proxy or any vpn and if you are thinking that the gradle is downloaded or not ..gradle4.4 all  downloaded successful  but stuck on daemon process...

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall every component related to android Studio even i uninstall android studio and all its settings and reinstall every thing and somehow it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I resolved `Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process` by adding Variable Name and Variable Path for `gradle-2.14.1`

[image]